# My android Onclicklistener

Tags: java, android

It's a simple practice. However, I couldn't find the problem. I did not understand the Nullpointer exception.  Can someone help me find the problem?

Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.jinyu.myapplication, PID: 8669
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jinyu.myapplication/com.example.jinyu.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.example.jinyu.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jinyu.myapplication.MainActivity">



<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Jump"
    android:id="@+id/Seattle"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

My java class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button btn;
private Context mcontext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mcontext = this;
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Seattle);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext,Second.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}


}
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.jinyu.myapplication">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Second">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: move `btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Seattle);` after `setContentView`

Comment: wow Awesome, but could you please tell me why do I need to do that?

Comment: ["onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically." ](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)